# Why can the static class Tuple in .NET Framework 4.0 have new keyword to create instances?

Tags: c#, oop, c#-4.0, static, tuples

[Static Classes and Static Class Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

In this link  Microsoft says,

> a static class cannot be instantiated. In other words, you cannot use the new keyword to create a variable of the class type. Because there is no instance variable, you access the members of a static class by using the class name itself.

I learned static class the same as stated above. But for the [static class Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) introduced in .NET Framework 4 can have new keyword to create a Tuple.

> var population = new Tuple(
>                              "New York", 7891957, 7781984, 
>                              7894862, 7071639, 7322564, 8008278);

[Another example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383325.aspx#snippetGroup2)

Can anyone explain how is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The static [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class is a factory class: it's job is just to provide an easy to way to construct tuples.

In reality, there are 8 tuple classes in .NET 4:

- 7 Generic tuples you can create instances of, with up to 8 generic argument: `Tuple<T1, T2>`, `Tuple<T1, T2, T3>` and so on.
- The static `Tuple` factory class which centralizes construction of the above.

So, you can't create an instance of a static class, but you can have several classes with the same name, if they have different generic arguments.

Answer (score 5):

The [Tuple Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) is static and cannot be instantiated.

```
// does not compile
var population = new Tuple("New York", 7891957, 7781984, 7894862, 7071639, 7322564, 8008278);
```

There's another class, the [Tuple<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387185.aspx). This class is not static and can be instantiated.

```
// compiles
var population = new Tuple<string, int, int, int, int, int, int>("New York", 7891957, 7781984, 7894862, 7071639, 7322564, 8008278);
```

Comment: Yep, just call static Tuple.Create(item1, item2); instead of using new notation.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it looks odd is that your example is wrong:

```
var poulation = new Tuple( "New York", 7891957, 7781984, 7894862, 7071639,
     7322564, 8008278);
```

You are right to think that looks odd, because a: `Tuple` is static, and b: how does it know which constructor args to accept? That is because the correct line is:

```
var population = Tuple.Create("New York", 7891957, 7781984, 7894862, 7071639,
    7322564, 8008278);
```

where `Tuple.Create` is a **method group** of multiple generic overloaded methods, i.e. `Tuple.Create<T1>(T1 arg)`, `Tuple.Create<T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)` etc. The compiler has uses generic type inference to automatically select the correct 7 generic types, so your line is actually compiled as:

```
Tuple<string,int,int,int,int,int,int> population = 
        Tuple.Create<string,int,int,int,int,int,int>("New York",
        7891957, 7781984, 7894862, 7071639, 7322564, 8008278);
```

So: it is using fairly standard language features:

- generic type inference based on the parameters to resolve the correct `Create` overload
- implicit type inference (`var`) based on the return type of the method

Answer (score 2):

It's actually quite simple:

There exists the static [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class that is a factory for the non-static [`Tuple<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386941.aspx), [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx), `Tuple<T1, T2, ...>` classes. Note the difference in generic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about two different types one is static that u can't create instance and second one is generic with constructors.